# GraphQL query the implementation class properties but in schema i mentioned only interface how?

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I have declared a model class like the below.

```
public class FunctionalOrganization : IOrganization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LegalName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IAddress LegalAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And IAddress interface looks like below

```
public interface IAddress : IModel
{
  string PrimaryLine { get; set; }
  string AdditionalLine { get; set; }
  string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And implementation (UnitedStatesAddress) (one of the) of IAddres is like below

```
public class UnitedStatesAddress : IAddress
{
    public string PrimaryLine { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalLine { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

If i want to query the Graphql api to fetch the City, Zip and State from IAddress it is not giving and showing an error.

```
 query {
  organizationById (organizationId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"){
legalName
legalAddress {
  country
  primaryLine
  additionalLine
  state
}
id
registeredOn
asResponder {
   settings {
     isVisible
     dataCenterLocation
   }
}
  }
}
```

and the  error looks like below.

```
  {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The field `state` does not exist on the type `Address`.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 7
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "organizationById",
        "legalAddress"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "type": "Address",
        "field": "state",
        "responseName": "state",
        "specifiedBy": "http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Selections-on-Objects-Interfaces-and-Unions-Types"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could some one help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: you should add state to IAdress, because the LegalAdress have IAdress as type not UnitedStateAdress

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the implementation of the interface in the query

```
 query {
  organizationById (organizationId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"){
     legalName
     legalAddress {
       country
      primaryLine
      additionalLine
      ... on UnitedStatesAddress {
         state
      }
    }
     id
     registeredOn
     asResponder {
       settings {
         isVisible
         dataCenterLocation
       }
    }
  }
}
```